# SWI-Prolog predicates are not called

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a game similar to minesweeper and i am trying to count the number of bombs near a point on a map but it only enters in one countneighbour and it stops, how can I make it enter the other countneighbor predicates?

```
checkneighbours(X,Y) :- nb_setval(vecini,0),
        X1 is X-1,
        X2 is X+1,
        Y1 is Y-1,
        Y2 is Y+1,
        countneighbours(X1,Y),
        countneighbours(X1,Y1),
        countneighbours(X1,Y2),
        countneighbours(X,Y1),
        countneighbours(X,Y2),
        countneighbours(X2,Y1),
        countneighbours(X2,Y),
        countneighbours(X2,Y2),
        nb_getval(V,vecini),
         write(V).

countneighbours(X,Y) :- map(X,Y,Z),
                ( Z=:= "O"
                        -> nb_getval(V,vecini),
                        V1 is V+1,
                        nb_setval(vecini,V1)
                ).
```

Comment: What is your `map` predicate? And really, a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole approach is a bit questionable, global variables, copy-pasting instead of using back-tracking, etc. How do you represent the whole playing field?

Anyway, the if-else construct will fail when the else hits. You need to write something like:

```
(  if_condition
-> action
;  true
).
```

if there is no action associated with the else.

But it could be something else, of course... What does `map` do?

Comment: I guess map/3 it's the minefield

Comment: @CapelliC I guess so too, but without its definition there is no way of knowing what values the Z in `countneighbours` could have

Comment: setting the else to true solved the problem, map is a predefined term in SWI-Prolog, you set it's size, size(2,2) for example and you set the values for the map, map(2,2,'a'), map(1,2,'b'), etc.